# Using Replace function for GA UTM parameters

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, google-analytics

I've got multiple types of clients: Loyalty, Account, Guest in Marketing Cloud. Depending on their type (a field in a Data Extension/Profile Attribute), I would like to display a different value for the UTM parameter source that is populated in the _EmailAttribute1 field.

Example:

> Loyalty: utm_source=_loyal
>
> Account: utm_souce=_account
>
> Guest: utm_source=_guest

So far, I've been able to use `utm_source=%%=Replace([Account_type],"Loyalty","_loyal")=%%` for one segment, but if I try putting more either inside the function or back to back, the functions don't work. I don't think I can really use complex AMPScript "if" statements because I need to enter that code inside the `_EmailAttribute` text field.

Anybody has a clue on how to implement this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use in-line AMPScript functions in your [**Web Analytics Connector**](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/integrated_products__crm_and_web_analytic_solutions/web_analytics_connector/) configuration.

A few [**iif()**](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/utilities_ampscript_functions/iif/) statements should do the trick:

```
utm_source=%%=iif(AttributeValue("Account_type") == "Loyalty", "_loyal", iif(AttributeValue("Account_type") == "Account", "_account", iif(AttributeValue("Account_type") == "Guest", "_guest","")))=%%
```